# Python TCP server closes if client disconnects from it

Tags: python, c#, tcp

Here is the code of my TCP server
PYTHON:

```
import socket
from cookieLED import callLED

host = ''
port = 5459

storedValue = "Hello!"

def setupServer():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print("Socket created.")
    try:
        s.bind((host, port))
    except socket.error as msg:
        print(msg)
    print("Socket bind comlete.")
    return s

def setupConnection():
    s.listen(1) # Allows one connection at a time.
    conn, address = s.accept()
    print("Connected to: " + address[0] + ":" + str(address[1]))
    return conn

def GET():
    reply = storedValue
    return reply

def REPEAT(dataMessage):
    reply = dataMessage[1]
    return reply

def dataTransfer(conn):
    # A big loop that sends/receives data until told not to.
    while True:
        # Receive the data
        data = conn.recv(1024) # receive the data
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        # Split the data such that you separate the command
        # from the rest of the data.
        dataMessage = data.split(' ', 1)
        command = dataMessage[0]
        if command == 'GET':
            reply = GET()
        elif command == 'REPEAT':
            reply = REPEAT(dataMessage)
        elif command == 'LED_ON':
            callLED()
            reply = 'LED was on'
        elif command == 'EXIT':
            print("Our client has left us :(")
            break
        elif command == 'KILL':
            print("Our server is shutting down.")
            s.close()
            break
        else:
            reply = 'Unknown Command'
        # Send the reply back to the client
        conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
        print("Data has been sent!")
   # conn.close()


s = setupServer()

while True:
    try:
        conn = setupConnection()
        dataTransfer(conn)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        break
```

This runs on my Raspberry PI. I start the server from the RPI and then run a client program on my laptop which allows me to communicate with the server. It sends and recieves data without any problem but when i close the program from my laptop, the server terminal shows this and then stops:[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd28t.png)

TCP Client code C#:

```
        const int PORT_NO = 5450;
        const string SERVER_IP = "RASPBERRY PI IP ";
        string textToSend;
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            //---create a TCPClient object at the IP and port no.---
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(SERVER_IP, PORT_NO);
            NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textToSend);

            //---send the text---
            label2.Text = "Sending : " + textToSend;
            nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

            //---read back the text---
            byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            textBox1.Text = "Received : " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead);         
            //client.Close();

        }

        private void SetMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //---data to send to the server---
            textToSend = textBox2.Text;
            textBox2.Clear();

        }
```

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Please don't just blindly exit on an exception but print out the error and find out what causes the error. Then you might be able to solve the problem yourself. If not at least include the error in your question.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich i updated the code and image